# Can Emacs GDB-mode display expressions in separate window

Tags: emacs, gdb

In windowed mode GDB displays watched expressions in the speedbar. In console mode there is no speedbar.

Is there a way to get gdb to display watched expressions in a separate window? That might come in handy, windowed or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a speedbar in console mode. The name string of the buffer is `" SPEEDBAR"` (Mind the gap!). You get this buffer with <kbd>C-x b</kbd>. To get it fixed in `gdb-many-windows` you need `window-dedicated-toggle`.

The speedbar is actually just another frame showing the `" SPEEDBAR"` buffer.

There is even a page almost completely dedicated to the speedbar in a single frame setup:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar

The existing speedbar also solves your problem of displaying the watch-expressions in `gdb-many-windows`.

Comment: An easier way to switch to the speedbar in console mode is to call the interactive command `(speedbar-get-focus)`. The speedbar info manual recommends to bind that command to a convenient key sequence.